# Simplify log expression with infinite series $\log x - \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{i}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, divergent-series

How would I simplify the expression?

$$\log x - \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{i}$$

I'm fairly confident the series is divergent, if its not can you explain how it converges and where to go from there?

Update: The series can be simplified by a simple identity, due to the fact that it's actually a Taylor series expansion.

Comment: The series is convergent for $-1\le x<1$, and divergent otherwise.

Comment: Note that $ln(x)=ln(1-(1-x))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
taylor series:
$${\displaystyle \log(1-x)=-\sum _{i=1}^{\infty }{\frac {x^{i}}{i}}=-x-{\frac {x^{2}}{2}}-{\frac {x^{3}}{3}}-\cdots \quad {\text{ for }}|x|<1}$$

Comment: Wow. I completely forgot about that identity. Thank you. Is there a proof for the identity that's accessible with an undergrad understanding?

Comment: @CameronP see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series