# Estimating the difference of $\log 2$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{100}\frac{1}{n 2^n}$?

Tags: logarithms, power-series, estimation

How do I think of the sign of the difference $\log(2) - \sum_{n=1}^{100}\frac{1}{n 2^n}$ ? Is the difference less than  or greater than $\frac{1}{2^{100}.101}$?

I thought of writing the series expansion for $\log(2)$ as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$, so now I am looking at the difference $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} - \sum_{n=1}^{100} \frac{1}{n2^n}$, but how to proceed next?

Will it be helpful to write the series $\sum_{n=1}^{100}\frac{1}{n 2^n}$ in terms of logarithms, can we write it?

Comment: How about writing $\log2$ as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n2^n}$ instead?

Comment: The above series expansion of $\log 2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ was wrong?

Comment: Take $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1}$ and antidifferentiate.  Then try using Taylor's inequality.

Comment: In order to get the series I integrated $\frac{1}{1-x} = 1+x+x^2+x^3+...$ both sides to get $-\log(1-x) = x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{4}+...$, then reformulating it as $\log(x) = (x-1) - \frac{(x-1)^{2}}{2} + \frac{(x-1)^3}{3} - ...$ and substituting $x=2$, any wrong in this procedure?

Comment: @BAYMAX it's correct, but it's not **useful**  here.

Comment: So I should now have in mind $\log(2) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n2^n}$ right @LordSharktheUnknown

Answer (score 1):

Well the above comments helped me in knowing that $\log 2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n2^n}$, and this link - [Simplify log expression with infinite series $\log x - \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{i}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1937211/simplify-log-expression-with-infinite-series-log-x-sum-i-1-infty-frac?rq=1)

is similar to the question above, from which I think that the difference is greater than $0$ and is equal to $\sum_{n=101}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n2^n} > \frac{1}{101 . 2^{101}}$

Comment: That wasn't your original question, which was to compare the difference to $1/(101.2^{100})$.

Comment: Yes you are right!, illusions to me:( , how can we think of estimating the difference to $\frac{1}{101.2^{100}}$ ?